# Set limit on Ceph rgw user usage

Tags: ceph, radosgw

I want to limit each user on rgw object gateway (radosgw) usage that gets from `radosgw-admin usage show --uid=johndoe --start-date=2012-03-01 --end-date=2012-04-01`
Any way that I can set limit on these parameters from `usage show` command?
For example user johndoe can only have 1000ops per month or 1000000bytes put_object per month.

It's okay if there is a solution in nginx or in other layers of the Ceph object gateway stack.

Answer (score 0):

ceph doesn't  have any tools for limit request to rgw. you should use reverse proxy module of nginx for two reason :
1- Use caching layer in front of  rgw for improve performance
2- Implement limitation in receiving  requests to rgw.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use quotas on buckets and users to limit their usage. You can also set default quotas in your ceph config file `/etc/ceph/ceph.conf` for when new users are created the quotas will be automatically applied. [ceph rgw quotas](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/admin/#quota-management)